# Iterate values of Associative array if it has one object or more

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

My Problem is, I have set of arrays

```
$people =[{name:'Alan', hasChild:true},
    {name:'Alice', hasDetail:true}];
```

And other one is

```
$people =[{name:'Alan', hasChild:true}];
```

I need to print all elements.

I have tried in below way

```
for($i=0; $i<count($people); $i++){
    echo $people[$i]['name'];
}
```

The first one is working fine. But second one show an error like this

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/vp/pending_users.php on line 320
```

Why it happen? How do i overcome this issue

Comment: You can use `foreach` instead of `for` is more accurate.

Comment: Your array definition should be `$people = [[name => 'Alan', hasChild => true]];`

Comment: Second Array Has only one Element, so why are you using [$i] in Second Array

Comment: how can i do this stuff in one for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very basic stuff. You should read a few beginner's tutorials.

You can loop the array using a [`foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), like this:

```
$people = [
    [
        'name' => 'Alan', 
        'hasChild' => true
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Alice', 
        'hasChild' => true
    ]
];

foreach ($people as $person) {
    echo $person['name'] . "\n";
}
```